# Audio not working when Raspberry Pi startup (.bashrc)

Tags: python, bash, audio, raspberry-pi3, startup

I am facing a wired bug in my Raspberry Pi where my startup Python script can't play sound. I trigger my script to run at startup with `~/.bashrc` file. Here is the code in `~/.bashrc`.

```
# run python script
openvt -s -w /home/pi/path/to/script.sh
```

where `script.sh` will run python script. The code in `script.sh` is as simple as `cd` to python script and run it.

```
cd /path/to/project/folder
python script.py
```

Everything works great except the audio.

Here is the code in my Python script which will play the sound

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(['omxplayer', "/path/to/audio.wav".format(filename)], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=None, stderr=None, bufsize=0)
```

Note: I've tried running python script manually without `.bashrc` it works fine, there is no problem with audio. I also tried running python script in `/etc/rc.local`, audio works great. It seems like all script triggered from `.bashrc` can't play audio.

The reason why I don't run script from `/etc/rc.local` is that it runs as `root` user and has problem with my Ajax request, `~/.bashrc` doesn't have problem with my Ajax.

How do I play sound in startup script? Thanks in advance for any helps

Comment: Ohh sorry the problem is with my hardware. Thanks @Philippe

Comment: The problem is with my hardware. Sorry for making you confusing Philippe :)  I replaced the old one with new speaker, it works fine now.